# Merging a Select statement into an Update statement

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, advantage-database-server

Wondering if someone could prod me in the right direction. I've currently got this script (Advantage Arc), but I want to merge the 2nd select statement in with the Update statement so I end up with the first Select statement, and then an Update statement. I know this should be possible, but I can't quite get it right:

```
SELECT
    e.ident
  , LEFT(othersys_id, 16) AS sysid
INTO #epilink
FROM epidata e JOIN trainee t ON e.ident = t.ident
WHERE
  fundorg = 'PRV1'
;

SELECT
    e.ident
  , et.maptopicsethniccode
INTO #tmp
FROM #epilink                         e
JOIN [.._control\pics.add]._trainee   t  ON e.sysid = t.traineeid
JOIN [.._control\pics.add]._ethnicity et ON et.maytasethniccode = t.ethnicgroup
WHERE
  t.ethnicgroup IS NOT NULL
;

UPDATE
  epidata
SET
  ethcode = (
SELECT
  et.maptopicsethniccode
FROM #epilink                         e
JOIN [.._control\pics.add]._trainee   t  ON e.sysid = t.traineeid
JOIN [.._control\pics.add]._ethnicity et ON et.maytasethniccode = t.ethnicgroup
WHERE
  t.ethnicgroup IS NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "quite get it right"? What is the code doing at the moment? Do you get any error messages? What is the background? What are the table definitions? You should put a little bit more effort into the question if you want good answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is an update with multiple tables, this could be done using this syntax:

```
UPDATE
  dat
SET
  ethcode = et.maptopicsethniccode
FROM epidata                          dat
JOIN #epilink                         e   ON e.ident = dat.ident
JOIN [.._control\pics.add]._trainee   t   ON e.sysid = t.traineeid
JOIN [.._control\pics.add]._ethnicity et  ON et.maytasethniccode = t.ethnicgroup
WHERE
  t.ethnicgroup IS NOT NULL
;
```

I specified the alias to the table to be updated at the top of the update clause and pulled everything from the subselect into the main statement.

You can see the syntax with examples for ADS UPDATE statements in the documentation:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/master_update.htm

> CREATE TABLE a ( id integer, val integer )
>
> CREATE TABLE b ( id integer, val integer )
>
> INSERT INTO a VALUES ( 1, 10 )
>
> INSERT INTO b VALUES ( 1, 20 )
>
> INSERT INTO b VALUES ( 1, 30 )
>
> UPDATE a
>
> SET a.val = b.Val
>
> FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id